# Why is the array rewrites the all values inside the function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Javascript and I know that question is simple, but I guess that I have missed something. Please someone explain why the array is rewriting inside the loop of the function and how to push new values to this array?

This is my function that gets few arguments
I want each time to push new `td` value to the `rez` array, but it always rewrites. Where is the mistake?

```
this.rule = function(tr, td, size) {
    var rez = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rez.push(tr);
    }
    console.log(tr, td, size);
    console.log(rez);
}
```

Comment: `var rez = [];` ... read that a few times and it might become clear ;)

Comment: var rez=[] is local variable so each time you call rule function it will create new copy of rez . make it global yours problem might be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making rez as local variable so each time you are calling rule it will create new copy of rez variable create rez as global variable yours problem will be solved  You can try this

```
var rez = [];
rule = function(tr, td, size) {

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rez.push(tr);
    }
    console.log(tr, td, size);
    console.log(rez);
}; 
rule("tr","td",3); 
rule("t","t",3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're redeclaring the array each time you call this function. You should move `var res = []` outside of function.